# Is there an way to add an event listener to a node list?

Tags: javascript

I am building a sketch and I am stuck on making the relevant `div.block` elements (in `.gridcontainer`) to change on *mouseover*. I can achieve this if I change the query selector to `"div"` instead of `".block"`, however this is not what I want.

Likely I need to change the logic completely. How should I achieve this?

```js
let colours = document.querySelector(".block");

colours.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
});


let newGrid = document.querySelector('button');

newGrid.addEventListener("click", event => {
  if (event.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
    deleteChild();
    let userInput = howMany();
    let input = userInput * userInput;
    let pixel = 500 / userInput;
    for (let i = 0; i < input; i++) {
      let i = addGrid(pixel)
    }
  }
});

function howMany() {
  let userInput = prompt("how many?");
  return userInput
}

function addGrid(pixel) {
  let container = document.querySelector(".gridcontainer");
  let grid = document.createElement('div');
  grid.classList = ('block');
  grid.textContent = 'hi';
  grid.style.height = pixel + 'px';
  grid.style.width = pixel + 'px';
  container.appendChild(grid);
}

function deleteChild() {
  let e = document.querySelector(".gridcontainer");
  let child = e.lastElementChild;
  while (child) {
    e.removeChild(child);
    child = e.lastElementChild;
  }
}
```

```css
.gridcontainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 0x;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button>Change Canvas</button>
<div class=gridcontainer>
  <div class="block" style="height: 31.25px; width: 31.25px;">hi</div>
  <div class="block" style="height: 31.25px; width: 31.25px;">hi</div>
  <div class="block" style="height: 31.25px; width: 31.25px;">hi</div>
  <div class="block" style="height: 31.25px; width: 31.25px;">hi</div>
  <div class="block" style="height: 31.25px; width: 31.25px;">hi</div>
  <div class="block" style="height: 31.25px; width: 31.25px;">hi</div>
  <div class="block" style="height: 31.25px; width: 31.25px;">hi</div>
  <div class="block" style="height: 31.25px; width: 31.25px;">hi</div>
</div>
```

*[Snippet is also available at *Codepen*](https://codepen.io/hbz19/pen/KKRvezO).*

Comment: A common solution for attaching event listeners to dynamically created elements is [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes here. First of all you try to get the .block class elements with `.querySelector()`. But since you want all elements with the .block class you need to do like this

```
//querySelectorAll to get all elements with class .block
let colours = document.querySelectorAll(".block"); 

//Add eventlistener for the initial .block class elements from html
colours.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  });
})
```

Then when you increase the grid you need to also attach the event listener to the new grid items. You could do something like this.

```
function addGrid(pixel) {

  let container = document.querySelector(".gridcontainer");
  let grid = document.createElement('div');
  grid.classList = ('block');
  grid.textContent = 'hi';
  grid.style.height = pixel + 'px';
  grid.style.width = pixel + 'px';
  
  //Add eventlistener for every new grid added
  grid.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  });

  container.appendChild(grid);
}
```